# Does Bacigalupi's whole oeuvre take place in the same universe?

Tags: worldbuilding, the-windup-girl

I know that *The Windup Girl* takes place in the same universe as "The Calorie Man," and I know that *The Water Knife* is in the same universe as "The Tamarisk Hunter." But are *The Windup Girl* and *The Water Knife* in the same continuity---say, 100 years apart? In other words, is there a *single* Bacigalupiverse, or are there several? (Or do we not know?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word of God is [that they are separate universes](https://www.wired.com/2015/05/paolo-bacigalupi/):

> **When I think about it, your books all seem to happen along the same messed up timeline. Is there a Bacigalupiverse?**
>
> I deliberately say I’m not writing in the same universe because I don’t want the baggage. But yeah, there’s a package of obsessions that build a certain future. It’s always populated by politicians who refuse to lead, a citizenry that decided not to pay attention, and oops points—moments where we were sure things were going to be fine, and then they weren’t. Almost every one of the futures I have is not one that any of the characters would have chosen for themselves. They’re always like, goddamn, if we’d just done something different a little further back. That shows up again and again for me. I’m always a little melancholy.